# The Laplace transform resolves a function into its moments.

Tags: fourier-transform, laplace-transform, intuition

> The Laplace transform is related to the Fourier transform, but whereas
> the Fourier transform expresses a function or signal as a series of
> modes of vibration (frequencies), the Laplace transform resolves a
> function into its moments

Can someone explain what does "the Laplace transform resolves a function into its moments" mean?

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the statement with regard to the $FT$, but with regard to the Laplace transform, I believe what is meant is that for a function $f(t)$ the Laplace transform
$$
F(\lambda)=\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-\lambda t} dt
$$
can be expanded as
$$
F(\lambda)=\sum {1\over n!}(-\lambda) ^n \int_0^\infty  t^n f(t) dt 
$$
(when permitted) which can be iterpreted as
$$
F(\lambda)=\sum  {(-\lambda)^n\over n!}\langle t^n\rangle
$$
where $\langle t^n\rangle$ is the $n^{th}$ moment of $f$, defined as $\langle t^n\rangle =\int_0^{\infty} t^n f(t)dt$.

The same interpretation of the Fourier transform *does not* "express[es] a function or signal as a series of modes of vibration", rather it is a very similar (but two sided) moment expansion. The mode of vibration decomposition is if you consider each $\omega$ in the $e^{i\omega t}$ as a frequency, not by expanding in $\omega$.

Comment: what exactly is $<t^n>$ is in the expression $F(\lambda)=\sum  <t^n> $? Also did we use a minus sign somewhere?

Comment: I edited and corrected the answer. See if it is clearer.

Comment: Why $\lambda$ disappeared in the third expression for $F(\lambda)$?

Comment: thanks @enzotib